# Can't pass data from getStaticProps to the NextPage component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I recieve properly the datas desired with getStaticProps. But I can't understand why they are not passed to the BlogPrivate component. I have exactly the same structure in another file, and it works just well...

articlesStrapi is always undefined

Here is the code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { GetStaticProps, NextPage } from 'next';
import { ArticleStrapi } from '../../@types/next';
import Article from './article';

type articlesStrapiProps = { articlesStrapi: ArticleStrapi[] };

const BlogPrivate: NextPage<articlesStrapiProps> = ({ articlesStrapi }) => {
    
console.log(articlesStrapi); ==> return undefined

    

    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            //////
        </div>
    );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<{ articlesFromStrapi: ArticleStrapi[] }> = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND}api/articles`);
    const { data } = await res.json();
    const articlesFromStrapi: ArticleStrapi[] = data;

    return !articlesFromStrapi
        ? { notFound: true }
        : {
                props: { articlesFromStrapi },
                revalidate: 10 // In seconds
          };
};

export default BlogPrivate;
```

there is the result of a console log of the articlesFromStrapi in the getStaticProps :

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    attributes: {
      title: 'Article 1dgdrgdr',
      createdAt: '2022-11-22T13:28:16.243Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-11-22T18:02:50.096Z',
      publishedAt: '2022-11-22T13:49:16.161Z',
      content: 'dfdsf sdf ds '
    }
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    attributes: {
      title: 'fdsfdsf',
      createdAt: '2022-11-22T18:01:47.759Z',
      updatedAt: '2022-11-22T18:01:48.440Z',
      publishedAt: '2022-11-22T18:01:48.438Z',
      content: 'dsf sdf dsf dsf dsf dsf dsf dsf '
    }
  }
]
```

And here are my interfaces :

```
export interface ArticleStrapi {
    id: string;
    attributes: Article;
}

export interface Article {
    title: string;
    content: string;
    createdAt: string;
    publishedAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
}
```

Let me know if you see any mistake I could do...
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your data names are not equivalent.

The prop that the component gets is articlesStrapi and the prop that you're returning from getStaticProps is articlesFromStrapi.

Here is the correct code:

```js
const BlogPrivate: NextPage<articlesStrapiProps> = ({ articlesFromStrapi }) => {
    
console.log(articlesFromStrapi); ==> return undefined

    

    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            //////
        </div>
    );
}
```

Or by changing the prop name in getStaticProps:

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<{ articlesFromStrapi: ArticleStrapi[] }> = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND}api/articles`);
    const { data } = await res.json();
    const articlesFromStrapi: ArticleStrapi[] = data;

    return !articlesFromStrapi
        ? { notFound: true }
        : {
                props: { articlesStrapi: articlesFromStrapi },
                revalidate: 10 // In seconds
          };
};
```

Comment: I am stupid... Thx a lot !